# Retrying Event For SqlAzureExecutionStrategy

Tags: azure-sql-database, entity-framework-6

When working with SQL Azure, if I create my own RetryPolicy, e.g.:

```
        var retryStrategy = new FixedInterval(3, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

        var retryPolicySQL = new RetryPolicy<SqlAzureTransientErrorDetectionStrategy>(retryStrategy);
        retryPolicySQL.Retrying += ....;
```

I am able to get notified when a retry is happening which is useful to log.

However, if I use what seems to be the new recommended strategy with EF6 and Azure - i.e. a custom DbConfiguration class something like this:

```
public class MyConfiguration : DbConfiguration 
{ 
    public MyConfiguration() 
    {

        this.SetExecutionStrategy("System.Data.SqlClient", () =>
            {
                var strat = new SqlAzureExecutionStrategy();
                // strat. No events

                return strat;
            }); 
    }
}
```

I can't seem to find a way to hook into the retrying process. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Implement the protected method called ShouldRetryOn by subclassing from SqlAzureExecutionStrategy.  In that method you could put your logic to log or hook it into a handler as I show below.

```cs
public delegate void ChangedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

public class MyStrategy : SqlAzureExecutionStrategy
{
    public event ChangedEventHandler Changed;

    protected override bool ShouldRetryOn(Exception exception)
    {
        OnChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
        return base.ShouldRetryOn(exception);
    }

    protected virtual void OnChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Changed != null)
            Changed(this, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I ended up doing the same but overriding 'protected override TimeSpan? GetNextDelay(Exception lastException)' which I think gives me the equivalent exception information.

Answer (score 0):

If you would perfer to just log the exception or the retry, you can do as follows:

```
public class LoggedSqlAzureExecutionStrategy : SqlAzureExecutionStrategy
{
  protected override bool ShouldRetryOn(Exception exception)
  {
    var shouldRetry = base.ShouldRetryOn(exception);
    if (shouldRetry)
    {
      // log retry
    }

    return shouldRetry;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.*

Comment: Ill tweak my answers.